# Overpass api to find the speed limit for a co-ordinate?

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I receive coordinate of a vehicle and I need to find out the speed limit of that road at which this vehicle is at?. I know you can find maxspeed for a certain bounded box like this

www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][bbox=5.6283473,50.5348043,5.6285261,50.534884]

but that is if this bounded box area has ONLY one speed limit. So say suppose there was an area  which had two speed limit within the bounded box?

My second concern is how should i make the bounded box since I am just getting one co-ordinate at a time?

Answer (score 5):

Please don't ask more than a single question at once.

Your first question is not clear to me. The query will return *all* speed limits in the given bounding box, not just the first one.

Regarding your second question: You should use the [around](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Relative_to_other_elements_.28around.29) query instead of a bounding box. With *around* you can retrieve all elements within a certain radius around a given coordinate. Example query:

```
<query type="way">
  <around lat="5.6283473" lon="50.5348043" radius="25"/>
  <has-kv k="highway" v=""/>
  <has-kv k="maxspeed" v=""/>
</query>
<print/>
```

Also see the [language guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) as well as [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu) for testing your queries.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is if I set a bounding box that contains two speed limit say at point A is 40km/h then at point B its 80km/h , both point A and B is within  this box?

Comment: If you receive two results then both are within the specified box. Of course the ways returned might also extend outside the box because they are not automatically split at the box borders.