# OverPass API - SpeedLimit around a co-ordinates

Tags: http, coordinates, overpass-api

We are developing an application, that needs to find the speed around a specific location... We were planning to use OverPass API to first the speed and tried to follow the article mentioned below.

[Overpass api to find the speed limit for a co-ordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259655/overpass-api-to-find-the-speed-limit-for-a-co-ordinate)

The syntax of the around method is shown below.

http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][around=2500,8.5580957,76.880541]

But we are not getting any results...  Can anyone guide us if the syntax is correct?

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/47571/overpass-api-speedlimit-around-a-co-ordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The failure reason:** `around` is not a supported predicate in XAPI (please, see the original manual, https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Xapi). So you cannot use it in your queries.

**Solution 1:** You can replace `around` with supported `bbox`. For example, the query below works properly.

http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[bbox=-0.489,51.28,-0.436,51.36][maxspeed=*]

You will receive ~300kB of data

**Solution 2:** If you still want `around`, please use Overpass QL/XML:

- Overpass QL query: `way(around:2500,8.5580957,76.880541)[maxspeed];out;`. You can try it at http://www.overpass-api.de/query_form.html
- Overpass XML query:

  ```
  <query type="way">
     <around radius="2500" lat="8.5580957" lon="76.880541" />
     <has-kv k="maxspeed" />
  </query>
  ```

  You can try it at http://overpass-turbo.eu/.

As for me, Overpass XML looks like more readable. Also XML is preferred because XSLT can transform it to any other regular format.

Comment: Overpass QL is recommended these days, xml is the older format