# OSMdroid max speed in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I have been looking for near a month, and I am losing my mind. I am building an app for android that uses the `maxspeed:` in `osm api`, compares it to the current speed registered by the `location` class, and alerts the driver of the infraction of going above the speed limit. I am decently new to developing and thus can't figure out how to implement the query. 
Can I get an example of a query for the `maxspeed` from the OSM api or a link to an example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860208/overpass-api-speedlimit-around-a-co-ordinates or https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/37172/getting-all-maxspeed-tags for possible answers. In short: Just use Overpass API to query for ways with the maxspeed tag.