# Getting speed limit from overpass api

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to get the speed limit around an area from overpass api using this url:

http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];[maxspeed=*];way(around(5.6283473,50.5348043);out;

Any help or pointers as to how I can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OverPass API - SpeedLimit around a co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860208/overpass-api-speedlimit-around-a-co-ordinates)

Answer (score 0):

your coordinates are inverted & the radius is missing

https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];(way(around:1000,50.603,5.856)["maxspeed"];);(._;>;);out;